# webViewDidFinishLoad self-invoking?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

I am developing an iPhone app. This is the first time that I have ever worked with XCode and Objective-C, although I have lots of PHP, JS, and Java experience. I am now stuck with a problem.

I am injecting JavaScript into an UIWebView when the `webViewDidFinishLoad` function is called. That JavaScript includes injecting an iFrame into the body, and that is where my problem is. It seems that the iFrame that is injected, AGAIN, invokes the `webViewDidFinishLoad` function, causing an infinite loop.

Is this a common problem?
Thank You!
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

The hacky way would be to add a BOOL to your class to see check if it's the first load finish of the webview or not.

Another possibility is to set the web view delegate to nil after the first load finish.

Comment: Would this disable the webViewDidFinishLoad function from running again, because I would like it to fire again when a link is clicked to go to another page. It should not fire ONLY when an iframe is loaded. Thaks for your time.

Comment: I will try to do this: let the iframe only insert if the url changes

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making a change in your javascript injection code - assign an id to your iframe, and before injecting it into the page, do a check to make sure the id doesn't exist.  That way, even though `webViewDidFinishLoad` gets called twice, the frame will only be injected the first time.